# Best design for refactoring multiple tables with the same columns but different FK

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I currently have a database with multiple `Log` tables. The table is used to log the states of a process. A Process_Log has 3 basic columns which is the table `ID`, process `State`, and a FK to their respective Process table which is `ProcessID`

Lets say I have these tables:

ProcessALog

```
ID | State      | ProcessID 
---|------------|---------
1  | Created    | 24
2  | Created    | 32
3  | Processing | 24
4  | Canceled   | 24
5  | Processing | 32
```

ProcessBLog

```
ID | State      | ProcessID 
---|------------|---------
1  | Created    | 12
2  | Processing | 12
3  | Deleted    | 12
```

But I found a problem to this implementation. I would need to create another table if I needed to log another process. I figured I could simplify this by having a central log table and having another column named `ProcessName` to store the different processes like so:

Log

```
ID | State      | ProcessID | ProcessName
---|------------|-----------|-------------
1  | Created    | 24        | ProcessA
2  | Created    | 32        | ProcessA
3  | Processing | 24        | ProcessA
4  | Canceled   | 24        | ProcessA
5  | Processing | 32        | ProcessA
1  | Created    | 12        | ProcessB
2  | Processing | 12        | ProcessB
3  | Deleted    | 12        | ProcessB
```

But having a central log table would mean that my `ProcessID` can't be a foreign key anymore.

How can I retain my foreign keys? Is this a good database design?

Comment: Design depends on the business requirements like how you want to show log and process etc. Anyway to keep data in denormalize form in log  table is a good practice i.e. no fk

Comment: *"But having a central log table would mean that my ProcessID can't be a foreign key anymore."*  Why?  I see no problem using a FK in a table with more than 2 columns...  And your central log is so much better than duplicating tables for each process.

Comment: @Nic3500 Because then the foreign key needs to be dynamic. The table doesnt know which entity the foreign key belongs to